# How do I display the value of donation in the game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

There are in-game purchases in my game. I want the user to see the cost of the purchase before it is made (before adding the card and displaying the cost in google pay). With that, I know that for each country the cost is converted into local currency. I've seen this in other games and I want to do it in mine. You may need to use some API to find out the purchase price from google console and display it in the game.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial/displaying-score-and-text

Comment: You don't understand me. I want to display cost of purchase before donating. The price should be the one I set in the Google console with the conversion for each country. Since I can't manually set the price for each region in unity (and there's no point), maybe I can display the purchase price from the console in the game?

Comment: Maybe you don't understand me .. your question is too broad and I see currently no attempt to solve the issue. StackOverflow is about primarily coding related questions, not a search engine for a certain API.